# C# Multiple Function on click a button

Tags: c#

I have a problem but i don't know how to search about it.

I did a simple bot on Visual Studio with c#. When i write the link in a textbox, the bot goes the website and take title and then write it to another textbox. It's ok.

After, I create a mssql database. For example there is 30 line, 30 different link. When i click the button, I want the bot to go to every website on each line and take the titles of them to the database.

Can i do that ?

I am using Visual Studio

```
    private void simpleButton2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        verial(txt_kaynak.Text, "//*[@id='cph1_lblKabulTar']", txtbox_tarihyaz);

    }

    public void verial(string Url, string xpath, TextBox Sonuc)
    {
        try
        {
            url = new Uri(Url);
        }
        catch (UriFormatException)
        {
            if (MessageBox.Show("hata-1!", "Hata", MessageBoxButtons.OK) == DialogResult.OK)
            {

            }
        }
        catch (ArgumentNullException)
        {
            if (MessageBox.Show("hata-2!", "Hata", MessageBoxButtons.OK) == DialogResult.OK)
            {

            }
        }

        WebClient client = new WebClient();
        client.Encoding = Encoding.UTF8;
        try
        {
            html = client.DownloadString(url);
        }
        catch (WebException)
        {
            if (MessageBox.Show("hata-3!", "Hata", MessageBoxButtons.OK) == DialogResult.OK)
            {

            }
        }

        HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument();
        doc.LoadHtml(html);

        try
        {
            // Sonuc.Items.Add(doc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode(xpath).InnerText);
            txtbox_tarihyaz.Text = doc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode(xpath).InnerText;
        }
        catch (NullReferenceException)
        {
            if (MessageBox.Show("hatalı xpath!", "Hata", MessageBoxButtons.OK) == DialogResult.OK)
            {

            }
        }
```

Comment: Add the links/lines to a collection and then `foreach` loop through that collection to perform the operation

Answer (score 0):

First write code to get the list of URLs. It might look like this:

```
public IEnumerable<string> GetListOfUrls()
{
    using (var conn = new SqlConnection(connectionString)
    {
        var cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT Url FROM List", conn);
        var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        while (reader.Read())
        {
            yield return reader.GetString(0);
        }
    }
}
```

Then call it in your click handler and iterate over it, calling your method for each row:

```
private void simpleButton2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var list = GetListOfUrls();
    foreach (var url in list)
    {
        verial(url, "//*[@id='cph1_lblKabulTar']", txtbox_tarihyaz);
    }
}
```

Comment: And then, how do i print the result to the gridview for each line  ?